# Asking whether a Docker image is pullable?

Tags: docker

I'm making a Docker image mirroring script (pull, tag, push) and would like to know whether the particular version already exists in the downstream (target) Docker registry.

The closest I can think of is `! docker pull image:ver && something`. I'd like to give the `docker pull` a "dry run" flag that wouldn't pull the image, but just indicate if it's there.

I'm trying to avoid unnecessary updates and pulls when the needed image is already in the target.

`Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87`

---

Edit: I avoided this need in other ways, so no longer actively needing an answer. However, keeping this for the sake of comments and possible future discussion.

Comment: Would you already have the image on the local docker host's image cache? If so, the test pull would result in cache hits and no pulling of the layers.

Comment: No, it's a build machine so everything will always be pulled again, and again. I'm looking at another way to see if it's in the target system (not Docker related) and that will likely work.

Comment: You may also want to consider using a registry configured as a pull-through cache. That would allow your downstream registry to pull images on demand and not needing to manually sync to your upstream registry.

Comment: Looks like it isn't implemented yet: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1512#issuecomment-248041868

Comment: Note you can go to the API to pull the manifest: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image

Comment: To make the api easier, have a look at Jess's tool: https://github.com/jessfraz/reg